# Need help in reading a .csv file

Tags: machine-learning, face-recognition

I am new to Machine Learning and was trying out a ML model to identify facial expression. I got the dataset from reserach.google but I am not able to read the .csv file using pd.read_csv(). Is there a way to read .jpg file from .csv file?[image: Dataset looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Reading a .jpg from a .csv is a weird request. That being said, you can try using optical character recognition tools like the Google Tesseract framework. It has python support and it pretty straightforward. It works pretty well with printed text as well.
[Learn more about tesseract](https://opensource.google/projects/tesseract), [tutorial with python](https://medium.com/better-programming/beginners-guide-to-tesseract-ocr-using-python-10ecbb426c3d)

Comment: So this dataset can't be used for ML?